# How many sorcerer and wizard spells are there in D&D 3.5?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

While commenting on: [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/21493/760) I tried to give an exact number of all sorcerer-wizard spells in D&D 3.5.

Trivial searching didn't produce any results.

Therefore, how many spells are there, by level and class?

Comment: Which books are you including in this? The more splatbooks, the more spells. :)

Comment: All valid 3.5 splatbooks. I'm currently doing some awking on crystalkeep's list.

Comment: **All** valid books? Holy hand grenades...

Comment: This is what AWK is for :)

Comment: Given that there is at least a nod towards PC and GM created spells in the core rules, the number of all possible spells is theoretically infinite. In practice, yeah, most groups won't use more than a few outside of the published ones, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @GMJoe I detect the implication of "published" in the question, but it would improve it to make that explicit, yeah.

Comment: What constitutes a "valid" book? One published by WotC? One published under the OGL? One published on paper? One still available to purchase?

Comment: Well just make us count all the stars in the sky why don't you. ;D

Answer (score 19):

**1017 spells, as of 2005. This significantly does not include spell compendium updates or the latter complete books.**

Operating over this [list of sor/wis spells](http://chet.kindredcircle.org/), without filtering for sorcerer specific or wizard specific, for all books from 2005 indexed, we get:

```
0th Level
    Abjuration      1
    Conjuration     2
    Divination      4
    Enchantment     2
    Evocation       6
    Illusion        5
    Necromancy      3
    Transmutation   10
    Universal       2
    Total:          35

1st Level
    Abjuration      10
    Conjuration     19
    Divination      24
    Enchantment     8
    Evocation       13
    Illusion        11
    Necromancy      8
    Transmutation   29
    Hybrid          1
    Total:          123

2nd Level
    Abjuration      10
    Conjuration     15
    Divination      13
    Enchantment     10
    Evocation       26
    Illusion        22
    Necromancy      13
    Transmutation   41
    Universal       1
    Combination     3
    Total:          154

3rd Level
    Abjuration      20
    Conjuration     16
    Divination      10
    Enchantment     11
    Evocation       21
    Illusion        15
    Necromancy      20
    Transmutation   35
    Universal       1
    Combination     1
    Total:          150

4th Level
    Abjuration      15
    Conjuration     25
    Divination      11
    Enchantment     6
    Evocation       20
    Illusion        12
    Necromancy      10
    Transmutation   30
    Universal       2
    Combination     3
    Total:          134

5th Level
    Abjuration      17
    Conjuration     24
    Divination      3
    Enchantment     9
    Evocation       23
    Illusion        11
    Necromancy      11
    Transmutation   27
    Universal       1
    Total:          126

6th Level
    Abjuration      11
    Conjuration     8
    Divination      5
    Enchantment     8
    Evocation       12
    Illusion        9
    Necromancy      10
    Transmutation   30
    Universal       1
    Hybrid          1
    Total:          95

7th Level
    Abjuration      9
    Conjuration     11
    Divination      3
    Enchantment     8
    Evocation       12
    Illusion        4
    Necromancy      11
    Transmutation   19
    Universal       1
    Total:          78

8th Level
    Abjuration      9
    Conjuration     8
    Divination      3
    Enchantment     11
    Evocation       8
    Illusion        3
    Necromancy      11
    Transmutation   13
    Total:          66

9th Level
    Abjuration      10
    Conjuration     14
    Divination      2
    Enchantment     4
    Evocation       5
    Illusion        3
    Necromancy      5
    Transmutation   12
    Universal       1
    Total:          56
```

This gets us a total cost to learn of (renting access) 50*spell level = 210625 + 
4230 pages or 5 blessed books for 12500*5 for 273125 gp, A sizeable chunk of a level 20 wizard's cash and a seriously non-trivial amount versus the 340k gp a level 17 wizard starts with.

Comment: Nice, all hail awk!

Comment: I will just point out that you didn't write anywhere the actual number of spells :)

Comment: That list amounts to 1017 spells.

Comment: Wow, the only level for which there *aren't* more transmutation spells than anything else is 9th - and even then it gets 2nd place.

Comment: @Tacroy: This is why the advice when specializing into a Magic School is not to ban Transmutation :)

Answer (score 15):

While Chet's indexes are clear and useful, they are unfortunately not very complete. Notably, since the spell list's last update was in 2005, it is missing such important works as the *Spell Compendium* and the latter part of the Complete series (*Complete Champion, Complete Mage, Complete Scoundrel*).

A large database I know of is [IMarvinTPA's database](http://www.imarvintpa.com/dndLive/index.php). In addition to being searchable, it is available in CSV format.

Naively looking through the CSV sorted by Sor/Wiz levels, I get:

- 76 level 9 spells
- 89 level 8 spells
- 107 level 7 spells
- 148 level 6 spells
- 193 level 5 spells
- 201 level 4 spells
- 230 level 3 spells
- 280 level 2 spells
- 195 level 1 spells
- 64 level 0 spells

For 1483 spells, covering 6011 pages of a spellbook.

*However*, the accuracy of this obviously depends on IMarvinTPA's accuracy. While it does grab from a greater number of sources than Chet's index, it

- A) Includes some less than official d20 sources
- B) Appears to be one man's hand-written list (!), with all the errors and omissions that come with that. Just in the process of counting this, I noticed that the DB doesn't seem to have Surge of Fortune, even though it does include other spells from Complete Champion.

Another (probably even more comprehensive) database was the one published by [DnDtools.eu](http://dndtools.eu/), which is now dead for hosting Wizards material without permission. It was an SQLite database that contained 1935 unique *spell names* associated with the classes "Wizard" or "Sorcerer".

Grouping by (minimum associated) spell levels, I got the following:

- 103 level 9 spells
- 110 level 8 spells
- 126 level 7 spells
- 176 level 6 spells
- 248 level 5 spells
- 303 level 4 spells
- 303 level 3 spells
- 320 level 2 spells
- 232 level 1 spells
- 37 level 0 spells

[Go here for the SQL](https://gist.github.com/Ernir/4ab19f6affbe687ad76e). I have not gone further into investigating the discrepancies between the two datasets.

Comment: Assuming that list includes the Spell Compendium, which is almost entirely reprints, how does the list handle duplicates? And how does it handle spells that were reprinted with different (usually nerfed) effects in Spell Compendium?

Comment: Looks to me like it handles it the way additional sources and errrata in 3.5 are supposed to work - a spell overrides spells in earlier printed versions if it shares the name.

Answer (score 9):

From only the core spell lists for Wizards and Sorcerers in the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spellLists/sorcererWizardSpells.htm#zeroLevelSorcererWizardSpells) and some tedious counting...

[Level 0:](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spellLists/sorcererWizardSpells.htm#zeroLevelSorcererWizardSpells) 19 
[Level 1:](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spellLists/sorcererWizardSpells.htm#firstLevelSorcererWizardSpells) 39 
[Level 2:](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spellLists/sorcererWizardSpells.htm#secondLevelSorcererWizardSpells) 50 
[Level 3:](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spellLists/sorcererWizardSpells.htm#thirdLevelSorcererWizardSpells) 42 
[Level 4:](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spellLists/sorcererWizardSpells.htm#fourthLevelSorcererWizardSpells) Wizards 42 Sorcerers 41 ([Mnemonic Enhancer](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/mnemonicEnhancer.htm))
 
[Level 5:](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spellLists/sorcererWizardSpells.htm#fifthLevelSorcererWizardSpells) 43 
[Level 6:](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spellLists/sorcererWizardSpells.htm#sixthLevelSorcererWizardSpells) Wizards 43 Sorcerers 42 ([Mage's Lucubration](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magesLucubration.htm))
[Level 7:](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spellLists/sorcererWizardSpells.htm#seventhLevelSorcererWizardSpells) 35 
[Level 8:](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spellLists/sorcererWizardSpells.htm#eighthLevelSorcererWizardSpells) 35 
[Level 9:](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spellLists/sorcererWizardSpells.htm#ninthLevelSorcererWizardSpells) 24

For grand totals of **372 Wizard spells** and **370 Sorcerer spells**.

Comment: I admire your patience, mate.

Comment: ...mage's lubrication?

Comment: So many things I can't reply with....

Comment: @EricB The correction is only *slightly* better... One of those real but now-unfortunate words, up there with *pulchritudinous*. And when you consider that [the definition of *lucubration*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lucubration) is "intense nighttime study," yeah, I don't think it will ever recover its dignity.

Comment: Dignity? Pah ;)

Answer (score 0):

http://dndtools.eu/spells/

Filter by Sorcerer - 2542
Filter by Wizard - 2520

However, this does include multiple campaign settings, renamed spells and versions of the same spell from different WotC books.

Comment: I'm pretty sure site policy at the moment is to not link to dndtools because it is illegal (copyright violations, specifically), and we don't want to get into trouble.

Comment: @Dakeyras do you (or anyone) have a link to that policy? Because my well-upvoted answer links to dndtools' front page, too...

Comment: It's here: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/ The policy isn't so much we shouldn't link to it because doing so in itself is bad, the policy is just to handle it as a resource that could become dead links at any time. There are also valid fair use concerns, but it's harder to know what to do about that.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Link rot is a fair point. I'm going to assume that mentioning the main page as the *source of the data* (which both me and user14761 do) is OK. If that source goes down, so be it. (Side point: Chet's Index has been taken down in the past as well...)